# How do I change the max value of the progress bar to the number that the user input in the textbox? c#

Tags: c#, progress-bar

How do I set the maximum value of my progress bar to be the value that was input by the user in the textbox on my windows application form? Here is my current code. I need the max value to be the value that was Input. I also need it to print the current time and date.

```
private void btnProgNum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                     
    progBarNum.Maximum = 10;
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    int endProg = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumProg.Text);
    while (i <= endProg )
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        i++;
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged_1(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progBarNum.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblOutProg.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void btnProgNum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        int n = int.Parse(txtNumProg.Text);
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter != n + 1)
        {
            counter++;
        }
            progBarNum.Maximum = n;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

       }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 1;
        int n = int.Parse(txtNumProg.Text);
        while (i <= n )
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            i++;
         }
    }


    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged_1(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    progBarNum.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblOutProg.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Here is a update of me fixing the problem i had with the passing a new max value for the progress bar. Now I dont think i need a second while-loop for it. it works this way, but seems like it only is ment to require one while loop.